# How can you tell if text is bullet-pointed in a google sheet in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm working on a project where I need to determine if the text entered into a cell in a google sheet meets certain criteria. One of these is that it includes at least four bullet points. Knowing what cell I'm looking at, how do I determine how many, if any, bullet points are included in the cell?

I can't figure out whether they are actual characters that I can retrieve with .getValue() or if I need to check the formatting for the cell somehow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the value of the cell by using getValue() and then use regular expression literal to identify whether the value contains(•) bullet or not

```
function countOfBullets() {
  var openSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadhseetID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = openSpreadSheet.getRange(1,1,1,1).getValue();
  if((data.toString().match(/•/g) || []).length >= 4 ){
    Logger.log("Criteria matches");
  }else{
    Logger.log("Doesn't match");
  }
}
```

First you will need to determine the type of the bullet which will be used.

Comment: And if it is unknown which type of bullet is going to be used, will I need to just check every option that google sheets has?

Comment: You can define an array of acceptable bullets and then validate against it